# Convert PDF string binary representation to PDF

Tags: arrays, vb.net, pdf

How to convert string representation of byte() from server response to PDF? Response of pdf is like

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/Names 2 0 R.......
```

I tried to convert that text to bytes() using function found on Internet, and once it converted excelent, but now it doesn't work and I don't know why. Function is below

```
Private Function TxtToBin(ByVal Str As String) As String
    Dim bt() As Byte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Str.ToCharArray)
    Dim st As New StringBuilder
    For Each byt As Byte In bt
       st.Append(Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c) & " ")
    Next
    Return st.ToString
End Function
```

And tried to convert that string to PDF using code below

```
Dim path_pdf = "some path\test.pdf"
Dim txtBin = TxtToBin("%PDF-1.4 .........")
Dim bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtBin)
File.WriteAllBytes(path_pdf, bytes)
```

I get PDF which says it's corrupted. What am I doing wrong? If I don't use TxtToBin then I get PDF which I can open but all pages are blank.

EDIT//

I struggle with this problem because server response returns me 2 parameters. One parameter is unique ID which I later use for PDF name, and other is file of PDF (generated by server). Code is below

```
Dim message As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = client.PostAsync(linkApi, content)
Dim streamResponse = message.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
Dim parser = MultipartFormDataParser.Parse(streamResponse.Result)
Dim name_id = parser.GetParameterValue("paramString") //returns string    
Dim pdf_bin= parser.GetParameterValue("PDF") //returns string
```

Comment: You should not have converted the PDF bytes to string in the first place, not all bytes are valid code points.

Comment: It's multipart response from server, and using MultipartFormDataParser gives me only string response of params. There are 2 params of response, one is string JSON, and other is file in binary, but this parser returns me only strings.

Comment: Then you've got to replace the broken `MultipartFormDataParser` with something that works. I don't know where you got it from, but it falsely assumes that all form parts are treatable as strings.

Comment: Or if you use [this one](https://github.com/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser), use the `parser.Files` list.

Comment: @CodeCaster that the parser I am using, but parser.files is empty, nothing inside that property

Comment: Then you gotta debug what the server actually returns, using Fiddler or something like that.